# Is there a good way to express a dependency on an unpublished NPM version?

Tags: github, npm, version, dependency-management

We frequently run into this problem where our two main modules need to be kept in sync with each other. Features get developed in branches, reviewed, merged into master, and then the branch gets deleted.

Let's say module A, version 1.3.1 requires B version 2.4.0. Neither has been merged to master, and neither has been published to NPM. We don't synchronise code review, so we don't really know which will get published first.

Currently we have two choices for the dependency we express in A:

#### Option 1

`"moduleB": "2.4.0"`

Problem: you can't actually install this until module B gets published to NPM. `npm link` works for the main developers, but it's still bad having something that can't be installed in `master`.

#### Option 2

`"moduleB": "ourOrg/moduleB#newFeature"`

Problem: you can install this now, but as soon as newFeature gets merged, that branch will be deleted, and this will break.

#### What to do?

Is there a standard solution to this problem? I guess we could create extra branches that don't get deleted?